# Error once unity got updated to 2017.1

Tags: 2d, unityscript

I am working on a 2D platformer and I decided to update unity to the lastest version. Everything went well but once I got the project updated I got 2 error that I am not sure how to fix. Some help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is what the console is saying

```
Assets/Scripts/GameMaster.cs(148,112): error CS0039: Cannot convert type UnityEngine.Transform' to UnityEngine.GameObject' via a built-in conversion

Assets/Scripts/GameMaster.cs(111,96): error CS0039: Cannot convert type UnityEngine.Transform' to UnityEngine.GameObject' via a built-in conversion
```

Here are the lines that it is pointing to

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate (spawnPrefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;

GameObject _clone = Instantiate(_enemy.deathParticles, _enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of `spawnPrefab` and `_enemy.deathParticles` ? If they're defined as `Transform` type then `Instantiate` will return to you a `Transform`, not its enclosing `GameObject` directly.

Answer (score 1):

What is the variable type of *spawnPoint* if it is *GameObject* change it into *Transform*.

Define another variable as

```
public Transform enemyPos;
```

Now change the code for enemy instantiate

```
GameObject _clone = Instantiate(_enemy.deathParticles, enemyPos.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Now drag the *spawnPoint* and *enemy* GameObjects to the *spawnPoint* and *enemyPos* variables respectively...

The error is happening because *position* and *rotation* are properties of *Transform* class not *GameObject*